# grunt-ts error after compiling

Tags: gruntjs, typescript

having problem getting started with grunt-ts.
I've got one src folder in my project folder:

```
  \src
    test.ts
    test2.ts
```

After compilation, i have:

```
  \src
    test.js
    test.js.map
    test.ts
    test2.js
    test2.js.map
    test2.ts
```

Actually, this is exactly what i want .... but ..
then the task aborts with an error:

> `Arguments to path.resolve must be strings`

My grunt config section is:

```
    ts: {
        dev: {
            src: ["src/*.ts"]
        }
    },
```

Versions and stuff: i today installed grunt-ts. Any ideas???

Comment: I got confused ... the js files were generated using vs... I ran the grunt file as postbuild event ... The problem persists though ...

Comment: I retried it with a different setup. Running grunt from the root of the project folder, instead of running it from a subfolder and setting the grunt basedir to the root of the project ... that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Arguments to path.resolve must be strings

That error is really generic. PS: I think the error is in grunt-contrib-watch

PS PS: can you share the project?

This is the error source btw : https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L116 the question is: what is calling path.resolve incorrectly? I'd like to debug that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. I cant share the current project. But I'll create a new project and then try to reproduce the problem.  If that works, i'll share that project with you.